# Problems with heroku - app crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
Dec 31 12:11:39 starvingapp heroku/api:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sabatsuk@gmail.com
Dec 31 12:11:46 starvingapp heroku/run.4464:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
Dec 31 12:11:46 starvingapp heroku/run.4464:  State changed from starting to up
Dec 31 12:12:03 starvingapp heroku/run.4464:  Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
Dec 31 12:12:04 starvingapp heroku/run.4464:  Process exited with status 0
Dec 31 12:12:04 starvingapp heroku/run.4464:  State changed from up to complete
Dec 31 12:12:12 starvingapp heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=starvingapp.herokuapp.com fwd=184.73.237.85 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Dec 31 12:12:19 starvingapp heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=starvingapp.herokuapp.com fwd=204.93.223.151 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Dec 31 12:12:21 starvingapp heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=starvingapp.herokuapp.com fwd=50.18.57.7 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Give me this errors. someone knows?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Comment: What's further up in the logs, describing where and why the app crashed?